# Notation in pointed Nash Entropy (or conjugate heat kernel measure)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, ricci-flow

Fisrt and second pictures below is from [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf), I don't know the mean of $f_{t_0-\tau}$.   Acoording to second picture, I guess that  $f_{t_0-\tau}$ is the $f(y,s)$ of
$$
K(x_0,t_0-\tau;y,s) =(4\pi(t_0-\tau-s))^{-n/2}e^{-f(y,s)}  \tag{1}
$$
where $K(x,t;y,s)$ is a conjugate heat kernel based at $(x,t)$. But I am not sure, since I think the pointed at $(x_0,t_0)$ should mean that  $f_{t_0-\tau}$ is the $f(y,s)$ of
$$
K(x_0,t_0;y,s)=(4\pi(t_0-s))^{-n/2}e^{-f(y,s)}  \tag{2}
$$

Besides, from the [New logarithmic Sobolev inequalities and an $\epsilon$-regularity theorem for the Ricci flow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0380.pdf) [NH14], the 3th picture below, I also think the $(1)$ is right.

So, I want to know what is the $f_{t_0-\tau}$ ?

> > [image]

> > [image]
> > [image]

> > [image]

Comment: t_0-\tau is just t. In the second picture,  Bamler use the notation that for fixed time $t$, if the metric flows backward, then he use \tau and hence $s=t-\tau$.

Comment: To keep in mind heat kernel flows forward and conjugate heat kernel flows backward. If you find the notation is confusion, you just choose your own notation.